# What is difference between get() and eq() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between

```
var row1 = $('tr').get(0);
```

and

```
var row2 = $('tr').eq(0);
```

Comment: This should really be merged with the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery : eq() vs get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the first DOM element matched by the selector.

[`eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns *a jQuery object* containing the first DOM element matched by the selector.

In other words, `$("selector").get(0)` is equivalent to `$("selector").eq(0).get(0)`.

Answer (score 9):

[The `.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a DOM element at the given index.

[The `.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns a DOM element at the given index, wrapped in a jQuery object.

Another difference is that if you don't pass an argument to [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), it will return an Array of the DOM elements in the jQuery object.