# jQuery : eq() vs get()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm wondering what the difference is between jQuery's `get()` and `eq()` functions.  I may misunderstand what the `get()` function does, but I thought it odd that I couldn't call a function on the returned on the returned element in the same line.

```
//Doesn't work
I.e.  $("h2").get(0).fadeIn("slow");

//Works
$("h2").eq(0).fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between get() and eq() in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662301/difference-between-get-and-eq-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between get() and eq() in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662301/what-is-difference-between-get-and-eq-in-jquery)

Answer (score 202, accepted):

`.get()` and `.eq()` both return a single "element" from a jQuery object array, but they return the single element in different forms.

[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns it as a jQuery object, meaning the DOM element is wrapped in the jQuery wrapper, which means that it accepts jQuery functions.

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns an array of raw DOM elements. You may manipulate each of them by accessing its attributes and invoking its functions as you would on a raw DOM element. But it loses its identity as a jQuery-wrapped object, so a jQuery function like `.fadeIn` won't work.

Comment: .get() returns an array, .get(index) returns the single element at the index from the array.

Answer (score 16):

`get()` returns a DOM element whereas `:eq()` and `eq()` return a jQuery element. Since DOM elements have no method `fadeIn()` it **fails**.

http://api.jquery.com/get/

> **Description:** Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

> **Description:** Select the element at index n within the matched set.

Answer (score 12):

[`get(0)`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/)  returns the first DOM element in the set.

[`eq(0)`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)  returns the first DOM element in the set, wrapped in a jQuery object.

That's why `.fadeIn("slow");` doesn't work when you do `.get(0)`. A DOM element doesn't have a `fadeIn()` method, but a jQuery object does.

Answer (score 6):

To build on the other answers:

```
$('h2').get(0) === $('h2').eq(0)[0]  //true
$( $('h2').get(0) ) === $('h2').eq(0)  //true
```

Comment: First one is correct. Second one is not.those 2 objects are not the same

Answer (score 5):

[`eq(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) retrieves the ith member in the receiver's set as a `jQuery` object, while [`get(i)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the member at the ith position as a DOM element.

The reason why this doesn't work:

```
$("h2").get(0).fadeIn("slow");
```

Is because the `h2` DOM element doesn't have a method called `fadeIn`.

You should use `eq(0)` here instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example that explains the points given by others here.
consider the following code

```
<div id="example">
    Some text
    <div>Another div</div>
    <!--A comment-->
</div>
```

and the corresponding js code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = $("#example").get(0);
    console.log(typeof(div));
    console.log(div);
    console.log("XXXXXXXXX");
    var div_eq=$('#example').eq(0);
    console.log(typeof(div_eq));
    console.log(div_eq);
    });
```

This is what you will see

```
 object
excercise1.js (line 5)
<div id="example">
excercise1.js (line 6)
XXXXXXXXX
excercise1.js (line 7)
object
excercise1.js (line 9)
Object[div#example]
```

The first is a DOM object while the latter is a Jquery-wrapped object where you could call Jquery methods

Answer (score 0):

jQuery eq() method selects a HTML element with a specific index number.

Here is an example of that

```
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>

$( "body" ).find( "div" ).eq( 2 ).addClass( "red" );
// it finds the second div in the html body and change it to red color.
```

Source:  http://www.snoopcode.com/JQuery/jquery-eq-selector

Comment: "it finds the second div" => doesn't `eq(2)` return the third div?

Answer (score 0):

Answers above have explained specificly and correctly. I want to add a few points here that might help for the use of `get()`.

1. If you don't pass an argument to `.get()`, it will return an Array of the DOM elements.
2. If you got a DOM object using `get()`, like 
   `var s = $("#id").get(0)`
   you can turn it back into jQuery object simply by using this, `$(s)`
3. You can use `$obj[i]` as an alternative way if you don't want to use `$obj.get(i)`, see below,

   ```
   var $obj = $("#ul li");
   var obj1 = $obj.get(1);
   var obj2 = $obj[1];

   //true
   return obj2===obj1;
   ```