# find previous node element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

After getting an element like this

```
$('.votes > a > img').get(0)
```

I am unable to call `closest('img')` on it. For example

```
$('.votes > a > img').get(0).closest('img')
```

I get an error saying there's no method called 'closest'.

But the following WILL work

```
$('.votes > a > img').closest('img')  // removed .get(0)
```

Can someone please explain why this is?

I really don't understand especially when I comare it to [this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YfCUE/1/). In the jsfiddle version there's a call to `('li.item-a').closest('ul').css('background-color', 'red');​` which to me seems the same as my `$('.votes > a > img').get(0).closest('img')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `get` with `eq`, see the updated jsfiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/YfCUE/2/

Basically, `eq` returns a jQuery object that you can reuse, but `get` gives you a DOM element, which is not jQuery and will not allow you to call `closest` or other jQuery methods on it. See this SOq where you have more answers regarding the `get` vs. `eq` difference:

- [jQuery : eq() vs get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get)

Comment: @Anurag Thanks, just did :) Or more correct, found a SOq that does that for me... :)

Comment: @icyrock.com thank you so much. I've been banging my head over this for awhile but you really cleared things up for me.