# How to I get an element by selector once retrieved parent by .get()

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am using `var slide=($('#accommodation-flexslider li').get(currentSlide));`.  This gets me the following html:

```
<li>
    <article>
        <img src="http://localhost/...">
        <div class="flex-caption">
       <h1 class="caption-heading">Patio </h1>
              <p class="caption-description">Enclosed patio...</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</li>
```

What is the jQuery to then get the text of `caption-heading` and `caption-description` using my `var slide`?

I have over 12 of these classes, so I need just the one that I have retrieved using my variable `currentSlide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `.get()`, the slide var will be a DOM element, and not a jQuery object. So you can't call `.find()` on it directly, like other answers suggest. But the jQuery selector-with-context syntax will work:

```
var caption-heading = $("h1.caption-heading", slide).text();
```

Or, you could use `.eq()` instead of `.get()` ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get)) so that slide is a jQuery object:

```
var slide = $('#accommodation-flexslider li').eq(currentSlide);
var caption-heading = slide.find("h1.caption-heading").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jquery .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for getting the text

```
$('caption-heading').text()
```

To find specific element you can use [Jquery find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
slide.find("h1.caption-heading").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using slide variable:

(note that if slide is a DOM element and not a jQuery object you have to do `$(slide).find()...` instead)

```
var caption-heading = slide.find("h1.caption-heading").text();
var caption-description = slide.find("p.caption-description").text();
```

or like @tcovo mentioned in the comments you can do it using context selector:

```
var caption-heading = $("h1.caption-heading", slide).text();
var caption-description = $("p.caption-description", slide).text();
```

If slide element have multiple captions you can use **.eq()** function to retrieve the one you want. Let's say it has **3 h1.caption-heading elements**, you can do the following to get the second one:

```
var caption-description = slide.find("h1.caption-heading").eq(1).text();
```

Comment: An alternate syntax is the jQuery selector with context: `$("h1.caption-heading", slide).text();`. With this form, `slide` does not have to be a jQuery object, it can be a DOM element.

Comment: .find wasn't working, I think it's like someone said above, it was a dom element and not a jquery object

Comment: @Nicola i put it in another answer, explaining why find doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicola replacing **slider.find()** with **$(slider).find()** makes find to work

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `find`:

```
slide.find('caption-heading').text()
```