# Getting child node value of child's child

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Below I have code to find the node value of 'TheNode'. I need to adapt that code so that it gets the node value of `<Child>`. How can this be done?

XML:

```
<BigParent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>Please get my value!!!</Child>
    </Parent>
</BigParent>
```

JavaScript (that needs changing (so I can find `<Child>` value)):

```
$(data).find('TheNode').each(function() {
  var childNode = this.childNodes[0];
  var childNodeValue = childNode.nodeValue;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(data).find('TheNode').children().first().text();`

Comment: You may prefer to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: Afaik `html()` fails on XML documents.

Comment: And what happens if I need say the 7th value rather than the first? (Just out of interest)

Comment: @JoelKidd instead of using .first() you could do .get(7) to get the 7th element in his answer

Comment: Joel: you can use `.eq(7)` or `.eq(n)` instead of `.first()`

Comment: @HamzaKubba Thanks very much. Shall select as best answer when the timer is up. :)

Comment: Frank: `.get(7)` may work but it note that it doesn't return a jQuery object:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("<BigParent><Parent><Child>Please get my value!!!</Child></Parent></BigParent>").find("Child").text()
```

returns the value