# Performance difference between using :nth-child() selector and .get() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to select every second `<td>` in each row of a table on my page.

Currently, im using the :nth-child() selector to get the target DOM. But I also find out another way to do this, which is using the .get() method.

The HTML and jQuery code is in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Litash/pV9ZU/4/)

My question is considering from the performance, which one is better?

Comment: The `:nth-child` selector is not related to the `get()` method.

Comment: both function are different

Comment: Also, you'd use `.get()` on elements you've *already* selected; so using the selector engine where possible makes perfect sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create performance test cases on http://jsperf.com

As is, I'd say that :nth-child selector should behave quicker, though http://jsperf.com/nth-child-vs-get (at least for my browser) disproves it.