# jQuery radio button events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive just started learning jQuery. I made a simple slider and i can't figure out how to put events on radio buttons properly in the way when i click on them, my ul would move margin-left on "-1*width_of_single_slide*radio_btn_value". It means when i click on first radio button(radio with value=0), the list would show the first slide and so on.. Or is there an easy way to make it without givin each of radio its value?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg1.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg2.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg3.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg4.png"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg5.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg6.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg7.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg8.jpg"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg9.png"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="../img/bg1.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<form action="" id="pointers">
    <input type="button" id="left" value="Left">
    <input type="button" id="right" value="Right"> </form>
<div action="" id="lowerBar">
    <form action="" class="stop">
        <input type="button" value="pause" id="pause"> </form>
    <form action="" id="choices">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="0">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="1">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="2">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="3">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="4">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="5">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="6">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="7">
        <input type="radio" name="changeBg" value="8"> </form>
    <form action="" style="width: 40px"></form>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
let width = 720;
let animationSpeed = 1000;
let pause = 3000;
let currentSlide = 1;
let $slider = $('#slider');
let $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
let $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide')
let interval;

function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        $slideContainer.animate({
            'margin-left': '-=' + width
        }, animationSpeed, function () {
            currentSlide++;
            if (currentSlide == $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
}

function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
$('#pause').click(pauseSlider);
$('#left').click(function () {
    $slideContainer.animate({
        'margin-left': '+=' + width
    }, animationSpeed);
});
$('#right').click(function () {
    $slideContainer.animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + width
    }, animationSpeed);
});
console.log($('input[type="radio"]'));

    for(let i =0; i<$('input[type="radio"]').length;i++) {
        $('input[type="radio"]')[i].click(function(){
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '='+width},animationSpeed);
        })
    }

$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    if ($('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true)) {
        $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-'+width*$('input[type="radio"]').val()},animationSpeed);
    }
});
startSlider();
```

})

Comment: where are you using the radio value ? you are using it's index, which is good. Also, you should use `const` on some of your  variables. The ones that you don't change their values. For example : `let width = 720;
let animationSpeed = 1000;
let pause = 3000;`

Comment: I didn't know how to work with indexes here so instead i used values, i previously tried using 'for' loop to put events on every radio button by their index, but it didn't work.

Comment: check answer below let me know if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the clicked radio button and use that in your calculations with `$(input).index(this)`

Read more about index here -> [jquery index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) which is the complementary to the `get()` method. Accepts an element and returns it's index relative to it's siblings.

See below

```js
const input = $('input[type="radio"]')
const slideContainer = $('.slide-container');

$(input).change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
    const inputIndex = $(input).index(this)
    $(slideContainer).animate({
        'margin-left': '-' + 10 * inputIndex
      },
      1000)
  }
});
```

```css
main {
padding:0 50px;
}
.slide-container {
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="slide-container">
  </div>
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="radio" name="changeBg">
    <input type="radio" name="changeBg">
    <input type="radio" name="changeBg">
    <input type="radio" name="changeBg">
  </div>
</main>
```

Furthermore if you want to find the slide-item that is corresponding to the clicked radio button you can use ( also in the `change` function )

`$(slideContainer).find('.slide-item ').eq(inputIndex)` and do something with it.

Read more about `eq()` -> [jQuery eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and about the difference between `eq()` and `get()` -> [jquery-eq-vs-get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709660/jquery-eq-vs-get)