# jQuery seach inside of container with find loses control of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need find info in `input` within a `table` in a specific row.

I have this

```
var myElements = $('#myTable tbody').find('tr');
console.log(myElements);
```

This show properly items in the table

```
[tr.rowcenter, tr.rowcenter, prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: document, selector: "#myTable tbody tr", constructor: function, init: function…]
0: tr.rowcenter               <- OK
1: tr.rowcenter               <- OK
context: document
length: 2
prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1]
selector: "#tRangos tbody tr"
__proto__: e[0]
```

In this case only had 2 rows

But when I want to look in a row, like this

```
myElements[i].find(".r_min").val(); //inside have .r_min , .r_max and .r_val
```

I get this

> Uncaught TypeError: myElements[i].find is not a function

When `console.log(myElements[i])` only see HTML elements

```
<tr class="rowcenter">
    <td>
        <input class="r_min" value="10.0">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="r_max" value="12.0">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="r_val" value="50.00">
    </td>
    <td> other trash</td>
</tr>
```

**Why?**

Note I use jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: `myElements.eq(i).find(".r_min").val();`, `myElements[i]` is a DOM node, not a jq object

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between get() and eq() in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662301/difference-between-get-and-eq-in-jquery)

Comment: Also `myElements.get(i)` is similar to `myElements[i]` which gives DOM node and `myElements.eq(i)` gives jQuery object

Comment: @jasilva does it makes sense now marking it as duplicate?

Comment: @jasilva and aint those two functions relevant to your question? I also explained you how they are relevant to your question.. anyways not forcing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `myElements.eq(i)` rather than `myElements[i]`. This will filter out all but the `i`'th row.

Comment: run perfectly!! spend more time writing the question thN  receive the correct answer :)